# Logstash does not process zero-length regexs in grok pattern in docker container

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I have to use zero-length regexp in Grok pattern.

I've tested it in  [online grok constructor](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match). It works.

But the same pattern doesn't work in my docker container. I've tested in Logstash v6.6.1, v7.3.0.
I've also tried a different regexp: `.{0}, ^$`.

Example of the log:

17:16:09,691 INFO blablabla

The Logstash pattern

```
%{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}(?<zero_length_field>())
```

**Grok constructor results. It is expected**

```
MATCHED
time    17:16:09,691
severity    INFO
message blablabla
zero_length_field
```

**Stdout results in a docker container**

```
   "severity" => "info",
   "time" => 17:16:09,691
   "version" => "0.3.0",
   "message" => " blablabla",
```

Comment: Set `keep_empty_captures` to `true`

Comment: Try `grok {
keep_empty_captures => true
match => { "message" => "%{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}(?<zero_length_field>)"}
}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you post it as an answer then? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `keep_empty_captures` to `true` as [by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-keep_empty_captures), it is set to `false`:

> **`keep_empty_captures`**
>    - Value type is [boolean](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#boolean)
>    - Default value is `false`
>   If `true`, keep empty captures as event fields.

So, use

```
grok { 
  keep_empty_captures => true
  match => { "message" => "%{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}(?<zero_length_field>)"}
}
```